# Proving additive inverse of vector set exists and "works"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let V = {$a_1, a_2): a_1, a_2 \in F$} where F is a field. Define addition of elements of V coordinate wise, and for $c \in F$ and $(a_1, a_2 \in V$}, define $c(a_1, a_2) = (a_1, 0)$.

In my proof, I defined a vector b = $(b_1, b_2)$ such that $a_1+b_1=0$ and $a_2+b_2=0$, thus $(a_1+b_1, a_2+b_2) = (0,0)$. My teacher wrote back that I needed to define b in terms of a. How would I do that if $(-1)(a_1, a_2) = (a_1, 0)$?

Edit: I know V isn't a vector space but I have to write a proof for each criterion. I've done all the others but need help with this specific one.

Comment: What exactly were you supposed to prove?

Comment: Do you want to prove that $V$ is a vector space?

Comment: Did you really say $b_1+b_2=0$ or is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For existence of an aditive inverse, we need not only exhibit the inverse of each element. We need firs give the additive neutral.

In this case, propose $(0,0)$ as neutral: Clearly $(0,0)\in V$. Next, if $(u,v)\in V$, then $(u,v)+(0,0)=(u+0,v+0)=(u,v)=(0,0)+(v,u)$. Thus, $(0,0)$ is additive neutral element.

Now, for $(a_1,a_2)\in V$, we propose $(-a_1,-a_2)$ as additive inverse: $(a_1,a_2)+(-a_1,-a_2)=(a_1-a_1,a_2-a_2)=(0,0)$. Since we proved that $(0,0)$ is additive neutral, then we have that for every $(a_1,a_2)\in V$ we have $(-a_1,-a_2)$ as additive inverse.

NOW, this is important: note that in general $(-a,-b)\neq-(a,b)$, cause $-(a,b)=-1(a,b)=(a,0)\neq(-a,-b)$.

On the other hand, is impossible describe a counterexample for each axiom because the law of the sum satisfies the laws for a really vector space. Then, for a counterexample, we need work with the product.

Now, in every vector space we know that $1v=v$, where $1$ is the multiplicative neutral of $K$ and $v$ is any element of $V$. But, in your case $1(1,2)=(1,0)$ by definition of product, but $(1,0)\neq (1,2)$.

Thus, $V$ isn't a vector space.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my question. I need help proving the additive inverse exists and works.

Comment: Thus I will edit my answer

Comment: Great explanation! I would qualify what you wrote about $-(a,b)$. Since $V$ is a group but not a vector space, I think the most natural interpretation of that notation is "the additive inverse of $(a,b)$", which is precisely $(-a,-b)$. If $V$ were a vector space, this would equal $-1(a,b)$, but it isn't and it doesn't.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Yes, I'm agree with you. But if I edit mi message, then two things: First, I wouldn't be honest. Second: Your point is important, cause it is a natural interpretation of a symbol. Then, i believe is better let my original message with your observation for other persons that would need read this excercies. Are you agree?

Comment: @sinbadh Sure!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Start with a particular example. Let $F$ be the rational numbers. What is the additive inverse of $(3,-4)$?

Now, can you generalize your answer?

Comment: I mean can I just write it as $(-a_1, -a_2)$? Is that valid or logical enough?

Comment: @p3ngu1n Yep, that's it! Then, you'll want to prove that it really *is* the additive inverse by carrying out the definition of addition in $V$.

Comment: (If you want to be really pedantic, you can mention that $-a_1$ and $-a_2$ exist and are unique as a consequence of the field axioms for $F$. But that is probably overkill for any reader, including your teacher.)

Comment: I guess I'm just overthinking this- I'm scared my teacher's gonna reject what I submit again because she's so picky with everything. Thank you!